# Magento - B2B install issue in 2.4.2

Tags: magento, magento2, b2b

I am very new to the Magento platform. I installed Magento 2.4.2 version on my VPS hosting server. Installed and running with Elastic search well.

When I install the B2B module in this version, I'm getting the below message. Hope others facing this issue can help.

`[InvalidArgumentException] Could not find a matching version of package magento/extension-b2b.`

My question: is there any difference between Magento open source vs Magento commerce? Magento open source won't support B2B? 2.4.2 version is Open source or Magento commerce?

Can anyone help me to clarify this?

Thanks

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/b2b/

Comment: @Wolfack I followed as per this method only. Because of version of package error. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The free version of Magento 2 is Magento Open Source. The B2B suite is Magento Commerce only (paid version).

So the B2B suite is not available on Magento 2 Open Source. To get the B2B functionality you need to upgrade to Magento Commerce or find similar third party modules to add to Open Source version.

Comment: Hi Gerard, Thanks for your clarification. Can you please help to recommend any third module which supports 2.4.2 open source version? I cant afford for paid version now as doing some study on this

Comment: @WTE It also depends on the specific functionality you want. If you want a basic suite, see: https://amasty.com/b2b-ecommerce-suite-for-magento-2.html. For more advanced options: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-b2b/

Comment: apply private and public key via composer and then try to install B2B in magento.

Comment: @RakeshGadhwal i tried this method.. still its not installing getting B2B version is not matching. thats why i got confused whether 2.4.2 wont support B2B or not. Still i am confused 2.4.2 version will support to install B2B module or not

Comment: @GerarddeVisser As per this link https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/b2b/ . They saying "The B2B for Adobe Commerce extension is only available for Adobe Commerce v2.2.0 or later. You must install it after installing Adobe Commerce.". I installed in 2.4.2. Then why B2B is not supported as per your above comment. Version i installed in Abode commerce 2.4.2 or not? Thanks

Comment: @WTE Can you check what Magento version you are running? Check your composer.json file in project root. Does it say `magento/product-community-edition` or `magento/project-enterprise-edition`?

Comment: "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)","version": "2.4.2-p1",

Comment: @WTE Was my answer helpful? Please consider to accept / upvote for future visitors.